# No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] while deploying service into PCF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, cloud-foundry

Hi I am trying to deploy a service which uses Spring Mail to send email. The service is working in my local IDE and I am trying deploy it in PCF cloud. I did a gradle build and have manifest.yml file on the class path. When I push it the app failed to start with following exception. Is that something I am missing or PCF behavior or email service will not in cloud?

I am using spring boot and I have all the required properties which helps to create a bean for mail in my application.properties file. It is completely working in my local.

```
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
private org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender com.send.SendController.mailSender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Update:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

private void sendEmail(String[] emails) {

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setFrom("************");        
    message.setTo(emails);
    message.setSubject("Hello");
    message.setText("Test mail from Spring!!!");
    mailSender.send(message);

}
```

application.properties

## mail properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.password=***********
spring.mail.username=*********
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=1000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
```

I have one more doubt, in my local it connects to internet to verify email and send email. How that it connects to internet in Cloud? I am new and appreciate help!

Comment: please show us your code where you autowire the JavaMailSender

Comment: It is a kind of same question but all the solutions were provided for beans created by self. But here in this problem, spring is creating bean for us. I have componantScan for all packages to make autowire working. Please consider this is as different question as the mentioned duplicate reference problem doesn't provide suitable solution.

Comment: @MinjunYu Your help is appreciated. I still wonder why it is not working.

Comment: When I got this error for JavaMailSender, it was because the properties I had set were in a different profile than I was running in (test, in this case).  Make sure that you're setting the properties for the correct profile (if you have any profile separation)

Comment: THIS was it. I only had the error in unit tests ... I had the options missing in the application.properties @ test